# Can't set a default value for the "weight" attribute

Tags: attributes, default

I am new on these forums and with Magento and i have a question about an issue i have been having with the "weight" attribute.

I have looked on many forums but could not find the answer i am looking for so i'd like to try it here.

My question:

I wanted to set a default value for 2 of the attributes used when creating a product. This because we use a certain shipment manager that requires these values to be set for each product.

For one attribute, i could set it without a problem (custom's description) but when i tried it for the "weight" attribute (fill in 0.1 for example) and save the attribute, the value just shows an empty text field again.

So it will not set a default value for that attribute, it just sets it back to blank after saving.

I have tried many things (setting the scope, setting it to be required, it doesnt allow me to remove it from attribute sets either) but nothing helps.

What am i doing wrong and how can i set a default value for this?

Hope you can help me with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't update the default attributes in magento. If you want to change the default value of weight attribute then you can execute following query:

```
UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET `default_value` = '2' WHERE `eav_attribute`.`attribute_code`='weight';
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I edited it in the database. It does show a default value now. I will monitor it for any problems but so far it works! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Weight is not a default attribute and the default cannot be set. You need wether to loop over the products to define a default weight or set for each product (that looks to me the safiest method). 
An other option is to create a new attribute that is called eg "weight_shipper" that you can set to 0.1 and that you can send to shipper.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly the extension could not use a new attribute so i could not use this option. Maybe it can help someone else :)

Comment: and about the loop ?

Comment: I have not tried that :)